# "Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source"

Tags: apt

When I am trying to use any command like sudo apt-get update then I am getting

```
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/ cloud-sdk: /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/ cloud-sdk: /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read
```

Here is my `cd` to `/usr/share/keyrings/`

```
rupeshiya@devil:/usr/share/keyrings$ ls
ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg          ubuntu-esm-keyring.gpg
ubuntu-archive-removed-keys.gpg     ubuntu-fips-keyring.gpg
ubuntu-cloudimage-keyring.gpg       ubuntu-fips-updates-keyring.gpg
ubuntu-cloudimage-removed-keys.gpg  ubuntu-master-keyring.gpg
```

Here is my contents of file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list`

```
rupeshiya@devil:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ cat google-cloud-sdk.list 
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main
deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main
deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main
```

How can I fix this?
I am not a very experienced Ubuntu user but trying to implement things in Ubuntu.

Comment: Try running `curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -` (do not remove hyphen)

Comment: Hey @Kulfy tried but still getting same error on sudo apt-get <command name>

Comment: I take it you were trying to install the **Google Cloud SDK** and it failed along the way? If so do you have a link to the installation instructions you were following? perhaps they missed something out.

Comment: Yeah you are wright @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I was trying to install google cloud sdk for ubuntu by following their documentation, here it is https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-debian-ubuntu

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the contents of file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list` please?

Comment: Hi @steeldriver, Updated question with contents of file ```/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list``` .Please help to fix this.

Comment: @Rupesh thanks - so I wonder if the issue is that you have **both** a `[signed-by=xxxxx]` and a regular *unsigned* version of the same repositories (hence the messages `xxxxx != `)? I suggest commenting out the unsigned entries (the 2nd and 4th lines).

Answer (score 50):

You are very likely to have followed the Cloud SDK install instructions to the letter. Some steps are alternative (ie, you do one or the other).

As a result, your /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list will have a duplicate entry:

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt  cloud-sdk main 
deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main
```

As you can see, both lines are the same except that one specifies a keyring file and the other does not (so it uses the default). There is your conflict.

You shall remove the line containing the 'signed-by' and you would be good to go.

Answer (score 36):

Here is how I fixed it:

Step 1: Remove sudo rm google-cloud-sdk.list

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
sudo rm google-cloud-sdk.list
```

Step 2: Reinstall Google Cloud again

```
sudo snap remove google-cloud-sdk
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg -y
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
sudo curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
gcloud init
```

Comment: Thanks, your guide is better then Google's

Comment: Google should use this as their installation instructions! So much easier to follow and less error-prone!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I think the issue is you are missing this file: cloud.google.gpg in /usr/share/keyrings/

To fix it you could do:

1. Remove google-cloud-sdk so you can use apt-get again:

   > cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
   >
   > sudo rm google-cloud-sdk.list
2. Install curl (in case you dont have it):

   > sudo apt-get install curl
3. Copy the key:

   > curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
4. Add source to list again:

   > echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
   >
   > echo "deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
5. Install the sdk again:

   > sudo apt-get update
   >
   > sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk

I think this is what worked for me but I am also not very exerienced so please if someone can provide further detail, that would be ideal.

Hope it works :)

Comment: Followed as per your instruction but now on 5 th step ```sudo apt-get update``` getting error as given ```rupeshiya@devil:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo apt-get update
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/ cloud-sdk: /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read```

Comment: Hmm that's strange... Could you attemp step 1 and then step 5 and make sure google-cloud-sdk.list gets removed from the folder. Lets see if we do this we can at least sudo apt-get update

Comment: yes, you are correct. After following step 1 and doing step 5, its working. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: You're welcome! Could you mark it as solved?

Comment: Step 4 is reintroducing the problem again, by creating two sources.list entries for the same repo but with different options (one has signed-by set, the other does not).

Answer (score 0):

These conflicts are typically caused by having multiple entries spreading in one or many .list files.

It's a tough exercise, but, do the following:

1. Locate the .list files in your system:

   sudo find / -type f -name "*.list"
2. Or, even better: Locate the .list files containing an entry that looks like the one showing up in the apt-get error messages (e.g: one for the microsoft repos):

   sudo find / -type f -name "*.list" -exec grep -l "packages.microsoft.com" {} +
3. You gotta select one of the files where the entry of interest (i.e. the repository URL) will remain. Comment out with a hashtag (# ) all the other ones, being them in the same file or in other files. Prefer to preserve the an entry containing a signed-by tag.
4. Ensure that the referenced .gpg file is present in the path referenced by the signed-by tag. If it's not, you must obtain and install the .gpg file, because this file is a signature that is checked by apt-get whenever downloading/updating content from a signed repository.

This might be enough: Run `sudo apt-get update` again. And good luck :-)!

Answer (score -1):

Delete all of the Google related files from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`:

```
rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*google*
```

Then try to reinstall them again.