# uninstall wine -stable completely from ubuntu

Tags: wine

Kindly advise how to remove  from Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.
Terminal runs: <E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ jammy: /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key != /usr/share/keyrings/winehq.gpg
E: The list of sources could not be read.>
Synaptic & Software Center run the same when get opened.
I tried all ways suggested in [How to remove wine completely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15551/how-to-remove-wine-completely) but got the same answer every time.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1458398/edit) to show the complete output of `dpkg -l | grep wine`

Comment: What is that in English? And where to find that <dpkg -l | grep wine>?

Comment: It means, in English, to open a terminal, enter that command, hit <enter> to run the command, and finally copy/paste to show us the complete output. Paste that output into your question above (not in a comment). If there is no output at all, show us so. We can show you how to install Wine the easy way, but your previous attempt must be completely cleaned up first. Therefore, we need to see the output to know where you ran aground.

Comment: ii  fonts-wine                               6.0.3~repack-1                             all          Windows API implementation - fonts
ii  libwine:amd64                            6.0.3~repack-1                             amd64        Windows API implementation - library
ii  libwine:i386                             6.0.3~repack-1                             i386         Windows API implementation - library

Comment: ii  wine-stable                              8.0.0.0~jammy-1                            amd64        WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS Windows programs
ii  wine-stable-amd64                        8.0.0.0~jammy-1                            amd64        WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS Windows programs
ii  wine-stable-i386:i386                    8.0.0.0~jammy-1                            i386         WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS Windows programs

Comment: ii  wine32:i386                              6.0.3~repack-1                             i386         Windows API implementation - 32-bit binary loader
ii  wine64                                   6.0.3~repack-1                             amd64        Windows API implementation - 64-bit binary loader
ii  winehq-stable                            8.0.0.0~jammy-1                            amd64        WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS Windows programs

Comment: I had to cut the Terminal answer in 3 parts. Sorry if the above is a mess.

Comment: Okay, you just showed us a list of packages. The ones marked `ii` are installed. Step 1: Uninstall all of them. Step 2: Remove the winehq source from your apt sources.

Comment: Thank you. So, how to do it via Terminal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156409/conflicting-values-set-for-option-signed-by-regarding-source)