# How do I roll back to Ubuntu 22.04 from Ubuntu Noble Numbat?

Tags: grub2, 22.04, grub-customizer

I am new to Ubuntu and I was using jammy Ubuntu 22.04 and I tried to update Grub 2.6 to 2.12 in the process it got updated to OS Nobula Ubuntu 24.04

```
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/ jammy: /etc/apt/keyrings/boot-repair.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

These commands I used to update (I installed boot repair and selected recommended repair:

```
sudo apt-get install -y grub-efi os-prober
sudo apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub2-common:*  
sudo apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub-common:* 
sudo apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y shim-signed 
sudo apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub2-com* 
sudo apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub-com* 
sudo apt-get install -fy 
sudo dpkg --configure -a 
grub --version 
sudo update-grub
```

How do I roll back to Ubuntu 22.04 from Ubuntu Noble Numbat?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. What was the purpose of updating to 2.12 and also please list all the commands you used in order to do the update. Thanks.

Comment: We can retract our close votes if you edit the question to provide more info.

Comment: Data points: Grub 2.06 = Ubuntu 22.04. Grub 2.12 = Ubuntu 23.10 and Ubuntu 24.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156409/conflicting-values-set-for-option-signed-by-regarding-source)

Comment: Yes, as user535733 said, upgrading the entire Ubuntu release is the only way to get a newer grub. You seem to be asking about the package errors. PPAs should be disabled by default after an upgrade. If not, follow my linked question or even move `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` away.

Comment: To be honest, I thought updating grub 2.12 will make system more smooth and reduce boot time and get better futures, but I don't know this will happen, and I am learning ros2  humble for that I installed Ubuntu 22.04 which is very good OS for me, but my lake of knowledge on Os I made a mistake, kindly please guide me to return to Ubuntu Jammy because I developed my small projects in ROS2 humble those may or may not work in Ubuntu 24.04, i don't how to get rollback

Comment: These commands I used to update (I installed boot repair and selected recommended repair, 
10.sudo apt-get install -y grub-efi os-prober
9.sudo apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub2-common:*
8.sudo apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub-common:*
7.sudo apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y shim-signed
6.sudo apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub2-com*
5.sudo apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub-com*
4.sudo apt-get install -fy
3.sudo dpkg --configure -a
2.grub --version
1.sudo update-grub

Comment: Please add additional details to your question; that is what will be answered. This is a Q&A site (*Question & Answer site*) and not a forum; comments are intended for readers to ask questions or make comments to *Original Poster*, and will get removed once addressed in question itself. Rollbacks will be via whatever *backup strategy* you put into place, and we cannot know that unless you tell us in your question.  Your question doesn't even tell us if this is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop, or a 22.04 *flavor* etc..

Comment: How do I roll back to Ubuntu 22.04 from Ubuntu Noble Numbat

Comment: Restore from your backups.. Debian/Ubuntu tools allow only forward (*to newer packages*) automatically; with *backwards* it's package by package & under user control - thus everyone uses their chosen backup strategy to achieve it.  You can *non-destructively* re-install a Ubuntu Desktop system, but you've not said what product you're using...  I've written about it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446102/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-in-the-easiest-way/1451533#1451533) on this site

Comment: @SUDARSAN In general, GRUB is not the bottleneck in boot time. Unless you set a constant delay in seconds, it is only responsible for the screen between your BIOS and the animated spinner screen with the Ubuntu logo. If you want to rollback, the safest and easiest way is to back up your files to a USB drive, then wipe and reinstall.

Comment: You should avoid "--allow-remove-essential" until you are confident in not breaking the system. Btw @mchid the asker does not have the reputation to see close votes.

Comment: To diagnose what's causing delays in boot, you can use `systemd-analyze`, usually something like `systemd-analyze blame`

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu does not have a built-in "roll back" feature. The design of Debian-based systems makes that too difficult.

If you have backups of your complete 22.04 system, you may be able to restore your 22.04 system from them.

If you lack backups, then preserve your data and then reinstall 22.04. For most folks, a complete reinstall is a simple and fast process.